# How do I manipulate layer text when using ember font-awesome?

Tags: ember.js, font-awesome

I'm using the [official ember font-awesome library](https://github.com/FortAwesome/ember-fontawesome) and I'm trying to add some text to an icon with the following code:

```
  <span class="fa-layers fa-lg">
    <FaIcon @icon="circle" @size="3x" />
    <span class="fa-layers-text  fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-8">
      27
    </span>
  </span>
```

From what I can see on the [documentation examples](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/layering) that should work but no value in the `data-fa-transform` attribute produces any change.

Is there a different method I need to use because FA now uses SVGs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember Fontawesome only handles turning `<FaIcon>` components into SVG icons. The reason your example isn't working is because fontawesome isn't doing anything to the `<span>` tag. You will need to tell fontawesome about this element in order to get the behavior you're looking for.

Do to that you need to use the [dom-i2svg](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/methods/dom-i2svg) method from fontawesome and pass it your element using [@ember/render-modifiers](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-render-modifiers).

```js
// app/components/layer-icon.js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { dom } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { next } from '@ember/runloop';

export default class LayerIconComponent extends Component {
  scanDom(element) {
    next(() => {
      dom.i2svg({node: element});
    });
  }
}
```

```
//app/components/layer-icon.hbs
<span class="fa-layers fa-lg" {{did-insert this.scanDom}}>
  <FaIcon @icon="circle" @size="3x" />
  <span class="fa-layers-text  fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-8">
    27
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: I suspected that was the case but had no idea where to begin fixing it. The above worked a treat!